# vb6 find value in a string add position and value to listbox

Tags: loops, vb6

I am using Visual Basic 6
I am trying to find the position of a value in a string
The find code seems to be working the issue is the code adds the information to a list box twice

Position 2 Value 2
Position 2 Value 2
Position 4 Value 2
Position 4 Value 2

The string to search will always be 1 to 9 values in some random order each time
The code as written now is only searching for one value

**My question is how to only add the Position and Value ONCE to the listbox?**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim S1, S2, MyPos As String
   Dim I As Integer

   I = 1
   S1 = "123245"
   S2 = "2"
   tbOne.Text = S1

   Do Until I = 5 'This will be Len(S1) - 1 later
      MyPos = InStr(I, S1, S2, 1)
      tbTwo.Text = tbTwo.Text & MyPos & vbNewLine
      'If MyPos = S2 Then
          lbOne.AddItem "Position " & MyPos & " " & "Value " & S2
      'End If

      I = I + 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you need:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim S1 As String, S2 As String, MyPos As String
   Dim i As Integer

   S1 = "123245"
   S2 = "2"
   tbOne.Text = S1
   
   For i = 1 To Len(S1) - 1
      If Mid(S1, i, 1) = S2 Then
         tbTwo.Text = tbTwo.Text & i & vbNewLine
         lbOne.AddItem "Position " & i & " " & "Value " & S2
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Note that you have to specify the type when declaring variables on the same line, unless you intended for them to be of type Variant.

Comment: I understand the Mid but when I decided to use InStr I thought that would be a better choice because I wanted to know the position of each value in the S1 String  so it looks like I will need another nested If statement in the For Next

Comment: Wouldn't the position of each value in S1 be `i`?  The code produces the same result as your code, except the duplicates are eliminated.

Comment: Yes the code works great I just commented because I was trying to walk before I ran Knowing the position or each value in the S1 string is the next challenge I only commented  NOT tring to ask another question